# Why would Quadratic Program in SVM not work for very large or very small lambda?

Tags: r, svm

I am wondering why Quadratic Program in SVM gives inversion error when I take $\lambda$ to be really small. $\lambda$ is really only changing the upper bound for the argument so I do not see how an inversion error would arise.

I used ipop in kernlab and solve.QP in quadprog.

If anything, a smaller $\lambda$ should make the problem easier because it is equivalent to making the range of the argument smaller.

Comment: What is the exact (error) message you got?  Perhaps if you show what you did (with exact calling sequences) and the output, your chances of getting a useful answer would increase.

Comment: I don't use an English system. But when I use $\lambda=1$ for ipop, I get something like,
Error in solve.default(AP, c(c.x, c.y))
system is numerically singular
and when I use solve.QP, the solution is a vector NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in quadprog with regards to the handling of very small numbers. I believe this explains exactly why your example fails, although solving the problem should be easier.

This is explained in more details at https://chasethedevil.github.io/post/quadprog-nans/

and there is a pull request for it at https://github.com/cran/quadprog/pull/1

Comment: By the way it has been fixed, as of version 1.5-8 (from 2019-11-20): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/ChangeLog Many thanks @fabienlefloch for debugging this.